# Pig: parse bytearray as a string/json

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig, elephantbird

I have some json data format saved to S3 in SequenceFile format by `secor`. I want to analyze it using Pig. Using `elephant-bird` I managed to get it from S3 in `bytearray` format, but I wasn't able to convert it to `chararray`, which is  apparently needed to parse Json:

```
%declare SEQFILE_LOADER 'com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.SequenceFileLoader';
%declare LONG_CONVERTER 'com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.util.LongWritableConverter';
%declare BYTES_CONVERTER 'com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.util.BytesWritableConverter';
%declare TEXT_CONVERTER 'com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.util.TextConverter';

grunt> A = LOAD 's3n://...logs/raw_logs/...events/dt=2015-12-08/1_0_00000000000085594299'
       USING $SEQFILE_LOADER ('-c $LONG_CONVERTER', '-c $BYTES_CONVERTER')
       AS (key: long, value: bytearray);
grunt> B = LIMIT A 1;
grunt> DUMP B;

(85653965,{"key": "val1", other json data, ...})

grunt> DESCRIBE B;

B: {key: long,value: bytearray}

grunt> C = FOREACH B GENERATE (key, (chararray)value);
grunt> DUMP C;

2015-12-08 19:32:09,133 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt -
   ERROR 1075: Received a bytearray from the UDF or Union from two different Loaders.
   Cannot determine how to convert the bytearray to string.
```

Using `TextConverter` insted of the `BytesWritableConverter` just leaves me with empty values, like:

```
(85653965,)
```

It's apparent that Pig was able to cast the byte array to a string to dump it, so it doesn't seem like it should be imposible. How do I do that?

Comment: What is Pig version?